# Deleting selected Item from Panel -JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code which works this way. when user selects checkbox, it appends the selected item name and price and calculates the sub total based on the quantity the user types in.

Now when a user deselects a checkbox, the item deselected disappears and the total reduces the  total to the old total (previous total).

What I want to achieve is, my html below I can icon `fa fa-close` which I want it to perform like how when a checkbox is deselected. So when a user clicks on the icon, it removes the respective item and also reduces the total to the old total

```
function order(food) {
  var ad = JSON.parse(food.dataset.food),
    existing;
  if (food.checked == true) {
    $('.panel').append(
      '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> ' +
      '<input type="hidden"  value=' + ad.id + ' data-id="' + ad.id + '"   name="food_id[]" />' +
      '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">' +
      '<thead>' +
      '<thead>' +
      '<tbody id="item_list">' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td  class="icon" ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></a></i></td>' +
      '<td  class="name" >' + ad.name + '</td>' +
      '<td  class="price" data-price="' + ad.price + '">' + ad.price + '</td>' +
      '<td><p class="total" ><span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p></td>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</tbody>' +
      '</table>' +
      '</div>'
    )
  }
} else {
  var total = $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().find(".total").text();
  $(".panel .container [data-id=" + ad.id + "]").parent().remove();

  if (total) {
    $('.checkout span').text(function(index, oldtext) {
      console.log('this is my old text ' + oldtext)
      return oldtext ? oldtext - total : oldtext;
    });
  }
}



$('.panel').on('keyup', '.quantity', function() {
  order_container = $(this).closest('div');
  quantity = Number($(this).val());
  price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));
  points = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.points').data('points'));
  order_container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
  order_container.find(".pts-total span").text(quantity * points);
  sum = 0;
  points = 0;
  $(".line-total").each(function() {
    sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
  })
  $(".pts-total").each(function() {
    points = points + Number($(this).text());
  })
  $('.checkout span').text(sum);
});
```

Comment: where is the change event for your checkbox?

Comment: @madalinivascu  the checkbox works fine when i select and deselect but now i want the icon to  perform how the checkbox is deselcted

Comment: did you even read my question?

Comment: @madalinivascu, this is all i have for my code. i am new to javascript so i may not understand your question well

Comment: where is the code for the deselect of the checkbox?

Comment: aren't you using a change event?

Comment: @madalinivascu the else statement of the function order is what deselects

Comment: i don't see any total recalculation there

Comment: @madalinivascu you can see that i find the total of the item that i want to deselect. After i get the total, i find the old text (previous total) and remove the item from the panel

Comment: so you subtract the current deleted item from the total? see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple click event

```
$('.panel').on('click','.fa.fa-close',function(){
 $(this).closest('.container').remove();//remove the current element

 var sum = 0;
 $(".line-total").each(function(){
       sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
 });//calculate the new sum 
 $('.checkout span').text(sum);

})
```

Comment: I am not able to reach the scripts with '$('.fa.fa-close')`

Comment: what do you mean by reach?

Comment: ups my bad, i forgot to delegate the event

Comment: The script doesn't run at all when i click the icon.. i consoled a text to see if it runs but i see it doesn't